# Cannot find device "wlan0"

Tags: raspbian, wifi, troubleshooting

Trying to configure Wi-Fi and Ethernet on a headless Pi Model B ran the following to get what I think is the correct version of the Wi-Fi dongle driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get rpi-update

uname -a
Linux ospi 4.1.13+ #826 PREEMPT Fri Nov 13 20:13:22 GMT 2015 armv6l  GNU/Linux
```

`lsusb` shows

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

`lsmod` shows

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rtc_ds1307             10383  0
i2c_dev                 6730  0
snd_bcm2835            22317  0
snd_pcm                92581  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_seq                61957  0
snd_seq_device          5130  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              23454  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    68161  5      snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device
mt7601u                87685  0
mac80211              622304  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              499834  2 mac80211,mt7601u
rfkill                 22491  1 cfg80211
i2c_bcm2708             6252  0
bcm2835_gpiomem         3703  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3690  0
uio                    10002  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
metric 1
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
metric 2
```

`wpa_supplicant.conf` contains

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
ssid="XXXXXXX"
psk="********"

}
```

`ifconfig` shows

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:fb:4b:ca

      inet addr:192.168.1.11  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1794 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:115957 (113.2 KiB)  TX bytes:79567 (77.7 KiB)
```

`iwconfig` shows

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`sudo ifup wlan0` produces

```
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Cannot find device "wlan0"
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

Any help on where to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `ifconfig -a` and read `man ifconfig` to understand the difference (also note the disclaimer there, *"This program is obsolete!"*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have firmware for this device. Just download this:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/porjo/mt7601/raw/master/src/mcu/bin/MT7601.bin -O /lib/firmware/mt7601u.bin
```

and reboot your machine. Now you should see **wlan0** in your `ifconfig` settings.